# import uploaded library to Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I uploaded the spark time series `spark-ts` library to DataBricks using maven coordinate option in the Create Library. I was able to successfully create the library and attach it to my cluster. But when I tried to import the spark-ts library in DataBricks using `org.apache.spark.spark-ts`. But it throws an error stating that `notebook:1: error: object ts is not a member of package org.apache.spark` Please let me know how to handle this issue.

Comment: Hi there! Flint is a package produce by TwoSigma, you can import it using 
`import com.twosigma.flint...` hope that helps :)